# What kind of sky and lighting is google poly using?

Tags: aframe

Super excited about poly and aframe, and apologies if this is a silly question, but i'm trying to reproduce this using aframe:

https://poly.google.com/view/9-b6-yqrwEe

I got this far:

https://code.sgo.to/arpub/docs/model.html

But it looks blend. I'm guessing I'm missing lightning to make it look smoother? Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

The Poly viewer uses post-processing (e.g., bloom). There's a PR open in A-Frame to add post-processing effects. You could start by increasing the light intensity and ambient light and adding lights from couple angles though and adding shadows.